# Bootstrap Side by Side Button Text Overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have web page where whole page is divided in two parts left and right. The partition is shown below. In the left section, I have two side by side buttons and one of the button having long text string as 'Edit Categories'. This button overflows the text and eventually collapses and stacks on top of another. I am developer but i am not really into designing. Tried using flex but seems not working. The expected behavior for this one is two buttons should be side by side in large screen and stack in medium small and extra small resolution. I also tried putting `col-sm, col-md, col-xs` on my divs which contains `<a>` but noluck.

```
 <!-- Start Left Section -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 animated fadeInLeft categories-lst">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
               <a onclick="toggleLoader('show')" href="/Rec/EditCategories" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><span><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit Categories</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
               <a onclick="showNewPost();" class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="showNewPost"><span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Post</span> </a>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Start Right Section-->
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 animated fadeInRight">
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes). **There is no longer `-xs`**... it's just `col-12`

Comment: I am sorry i might be outdated in designing. I just checked we are using v3.3.7 of bootstrap and our project still has all lg, md, sm, xs. Can you please guide me on the above snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
a{
    white-space:normal !important;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MVRwoN

Comment: Thanks but word wrapping doesn't look neat. I want to stack the buttons rather at the point where they wrap the text.

Comment: Yes, Pretty much but 'Edit Categories' button break the word at around 1300 width screen. I understand that anything greater that 1200 in width considered as large screen but how can i handle that not to break the work/wrap and just stack them ? it's stacking the buttons at/around 1200 width right now. I hope this make sense. appreciate your response.

Comment: can you share sreenshot , for me at 1300px, it is not breaking the word 'Edit Categories'